# How to copy the items of History Display from EER Diagram of MySql Workbench Community Edition?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to copy the items of `History Display` of `EER Diagram of MySql Workbench Community Edition`

[image: History Display]

The [Instruction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-history-palette.html) from the website is

> The History Palette Use the History palette to review the actions that
>   you have taken. Left-clicking an entry opens a pop-up menu with the
>   item, Copy History Entries to Clipboard. Choose this item to select a
>   single entry. You can select multiple contiguous entries by pressing
>   the Shift key and clicking the entries you wish to copy. Select
>   non-contiguous entries by using the Control key.

following the instructions no pop-menu as expected to copy the items of `History Display` and I can't even `multiple select` the entries

Does anyone know how to copy this items of `History Display`?

I am using the MySQL Workbench 8.0 64 bit installed in Windows 10

Comment: What happens if you right-click rather than left-click?

Comment: no pop-menu as expected